# Use generalized template class in specialized template functions

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm writing a wrapper for some benchmark code and want to execute the same code for every templated class type in an already templated function.

There is the benchmark class:

```
template<class T>
class Benchmark : public Interface, public T {
   virtual void Execute();
}
```

And as class T I want to use a type that is basically only there for initializing class variables e.g.

```
template<class S>
struct GenericBench {
    GenericBench();
    S var1, var2, var3;
};
```

The question now: is it somehow possible to define a specialized function Execute for every mutation of GenericBench for this kind of class inheritance constelation?

```
template<>
void Benchmark<GenericBench>::Execute() {
   // my benchmark code
}
```

A main call would then look something like this:

```
myBench->Execute<GenericBench<int>>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code compiled and linked in g++

```
struct Interface { };

template<class T>
class Benchmark: public Interface, public T {
public:
    virtual ~Benchmark() { }
    virtual void Execute();
};

template<class S>
struct GenericBench {
    GenericBench() { }
    S var1, var2, var3;
};

// Specialization of the class   
template<class S>
class Benchmark<GenericBench<S> >: public Interface, public GenericBench<S> {
public:
    virtual ~Benchmark() { }
    virtual void Execute() {
        // do things
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Benchmark<GenericBench<int> > myBench;

    myBench.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Thx, got this to work with microsoft compiler aswell. The problem with the specialization of the Benchmark class is that it consists of a lot of other functions which all need to be duplicated. Or is there a way to reuse code of the general implementation?

Comment: I understand that the specializations are independent. What you can do is use inheritance to separate between common and specializable code.

Comment: What if I had static code or a static variable which can't be inherited because it needs to be unique for each mutation?

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that you want to define specialized responses on basis of type you are working on... making function template and then specializing it will help.

Following is an examples
(Apologies for not using example u provided.. I just want to show the approach. Let me know if it works for you)

```
template <class S> class myData {
public:
};
namespace mySpecializedFunction {
    template<class P> void someFunction(P check) {std::cout<<"3333\n";return;}
    template<> void someFunction(myData<int> check) {std::cout<<"4444\n";return;}
    template<> void someFunction(myData<float> check) {std::cout<<"5555\n";return;}
}


template <class T> class myClass: public T {
public:
    template <class Q> void someFunction( Q check) {     mySpecializedFunction::someFunction(check); return ; }
```

};

And Using it like this...

```
myData<int> d1;
myData<float> d2;

myClass< myData<int> > c1;
c1.someFunction(d1);

myClass< myData<float> > c2;
c2.someFunction(d2);
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but since this question is related to benchmark code, implementing another function call into the execution function would mean overhead that should be avoided. Or could I somehow make sure my compiler inlines the code?

Comment: nenTi, B it depends on env where ur code is going to run. having one extra function call may not be big overhead... when you get clarity of code. I think having a namespace is more readable.

Comment: But it still doesn't solve the problem where I want to use one function for each myData. You have to either use the general function and therefore can't make two different generic types or have to specify the same function for each mutation.